# Listing trac wiki pages by username

Tags: trac

Recently we have installed Trac as our issue tracker and wiki. In the index page of the wiki you can list documents using "Index by Title" and "Index by date" i want to add another link "Index by username". Any ideas??

Comment: You'll probably have to write a macro yourself. Is username the user that created the page, or the last user to edit the page?

Comment: Valid question, but name it first/last author for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent hacking yourself, if you can live with the less elegant results table of [TracReports](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports). Don't get confused, it is not only about tickets. A custom query on wiki pages grouped by author is not too hard. Just make sure you query the first/latest version of each page, depending on you needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [ListOfWikiPages](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ListOfWikiPagesMacro) macro useful.  It's not as convenient as being able to do a sort from the index page, but you can use it to create a wiki page that displays whatever sorting/grouping system that you want to use.